# Mysql and apache is not starting

Tags: mysql, apache

I can not start the mysql and apache server in my localhost. It's saying me following error message:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
01:45:42  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
01:45:42  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
01:45:42  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
01:45:42  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
01:45:42  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
01:45:42  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Can you post logs please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please off the 80 port service from your task manager.